# Remove duplicates in a list of lists based on the third item in each sublist

Tags: python, duplicates, nested-lists

I have a list of lists that looks like:

```
c = [['470', '4189.0', 'asdfgw', 'fds'],
     ['470', '4189.0', 'qwer', 'fds'],
     ['470', '4189.0', 'qwer', 'dsfs fdv'] 
      ...]
```

`c` has about 30,000 interior lists. What I'd like to do is eliminate duplicates based on the 4th item on each interior list. So the list of lists above would look like:

```
c = [['470', '4189.0', 'asdfgw', 'fds'],['470', '4189.0', 'qwer', 'dsfs fdv'] ...]
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
d = [] #list that will contain condensed c
d.append(c[0]) #append first element, so I can compare lists
for bact in c: #c is my list of lists with 30,000 interior list
    for items in d:
        if bact[3] != items[3]:
            d.append(bact)
```

I think this should work, but it just runs and runs. I let it run for 30 minutes, then killed it. I don't think the program should take so long, so I'm guessing there is something wrong with my logic.

I have a feeling that creating a whole new list of lists is pretty stupid. Any help would be much appreciated, and please feel free to nitpick as I am learning. Also please correct my vocabulary if it is incorrect.

Comment: How do you know which of the duplicates needs to be removed?

Comment: Have you considered a separate `set` of the fourth elements already in the output? This would make the membership lookup much faster.

Comment: You're right. I guess I don't need the other information currently. Can you directly create a 'set', or do I iterate through my list of lists creating a list, and then call the set function?

Comment: @user3754225 you can `add` to the set as you go along, don't iterate over `c` twice!

Comment: You should check out pandas. If (as I assume) this is not going to be the last table-like operation you do on this data, pandas will be a very good investment. And your operation in pandas is just `df.drop_duplicates('col_4')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
seen = set()
cond = [x for x in c if x[3] not in seen and not seen.add(x[3])]
```

Explanation:

`seen` is a set which keeps track of already encountered fourth elements of each sublist.
`cond` is the condensed list. In case `x[3]` (where `x` is a sublist in `c`) is not in `seen`, `x` will be added to `cond` and `x[3]` will be added to `seen`.

`seen.add(x[3])` will return `None`, so `not seen.add(x[3])` will always be `True`, but that part will only be evaluated if `x[3] not in seen` is `True` since Python uses short circuit evaluation. If the second condition gets evaluated, it will always return `True` and have the side effect of adding `x[3]` to `seen`. Here's another example of what's happening (`print` returns `None` and has the "side-effect" of printing something):

```
>>> False and not print('hi')
False
>>> True and not print('hi')
hi
True
```

Comment: I'm confused about the 'and not'. is that the logical equivalent of if blah then blah? or is it something else completely?

Comment: @user3754225 I expanded the explanation a bit

Answer (score 1):

You have a significant logic flaw in your current code:

```
for items in d:
    if bact[3] != items[3]:
        d.append(bact)
```

this adds `bact` to `d` *once for every item in `d` that doesn't match*. For a minimal fix, you need to switch to:

```
for items in d:
    if bact[3] == items[3]:
        break
else:
    d.append(bact)
```

to add `bact` once if *all* items in `d` don't match. I suspect this will mean your code runs in more sensible time.

---

On top of that, one obvious performance improvement (speed boost, albeit at the cost of memory usage) would be to keep a `set` of fourth elements you've seen so far. Lookups on the set use hashes, so the membership test (highlighted) will be much quicker.

```
d = []
seen = set()
for bact in c:
    if bact[3] not in seen: # membership test
        seen.add(bact[3])
        d.append(bact)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use pandas. I assume you have better column names as well.

```
c = [['470', '4189.0', 'asdfgw', 'fds'],
     ['470', '4189.0', 'qwer', 'fds'],
     ['470', '4189.0', 'qwer', 'dsfs fdv']]
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(c, columns=['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3', 'col_4'])
df.drop_duplicates('col_4', inplace=True)
print df
```

---

```
  col_1   col_2   col_3     col_4
0   470  4189.0  asdfgw       fds
2   470  4189.0    qwer  dsfs fdv
```