# Remove duplicates in each list of a list of lists

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have a list of lists:

```
a = [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
     [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0],
     [3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0],
     [1.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0],
     [5.0, 5.0, 5.0], 
     [1.0]
    ]
```

What I need to do is remove all the duplicates in the list of lists and keep the previous sequence. Such as

```
a = [[1.0],
     [2.0, 3.0, 4.0],
     [3.0, 5.0],
     [1.0, 4.0, 5.0],
     [5.0], 
     [1.0]
    ]
```

Answer (score 4):

If order is important, you can just compare to the set of items seen so far:

```
a = [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
     [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0],
     [3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0],
     [1.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0],
     [5.0, 5.0, 5.0], 
     [1.0]]

for index, lst in enumerate(a):
    seen = set()
    a[index] = [i for i in lst if i not in seen and seen.add(i) is None]
```

Here `i` is added to `seen` as a side-effect, using Python's lazy `and` evaluation; `seen.add(i)` is only called where the first check (`i not in seen`) evaluates `True`.

*Attribution: I saw this technique yesterday from [@timgeb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24295657/3001761)*.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the OrderedDict (in Python 2.7 on), abusing it a good way to do this:

```
import collections
import pprint

a = [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
     [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0],
     [3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0],
     [1.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0],
     [5.0, 5.0, 5.0], 
     [1.0]
    ]

b = [list(collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys(i)) for i in a]


pprint.pprint(b, width = 40)
```

Outputs:

```
[[1.0],
 [2.0, 3.0, 4.0],
 [3.0, 5.0],
 [1.0, 4.0, 5.0],
 [5.0],
 [1.0]]
```

Comment: Good point. I was looking at the 3 docs, forgot about the backporting.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

```
a = [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
 [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0],
 [3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0],
 [1.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0],
 [5.0, 5.0, 5.0], 
 [1.0]
]

for _ in range(len(a)):
    a[_] = sorted(list(set(a[_]))) 

print a
```

OUTPUT:

```
[[1.0], [2.0, 3.0, 4.0], [3.0, 5.0], [1.0, 4.0, 5.0], [5.0], [1.0]]
```

Comment: sets are arbitrarily ordered, they *have no order.* This is not the way to do it.

Comment: Now, I used sorted(). To make things in order (sorted ascending).

Comment: But he wants the original order, not independently sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by DOSHI, here's another way, probably best way for a small number of possible elements (i.e. a small number of index lookups for sorted) otherwise a way that remembers insertion order may be better:

```
b = [sorted(set(i), key=i.index) for i in a]
```

So just to compare the methods, a seen set versus sorting a set by an original index lookup:

```
>>> setup = 'l = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]*100'
>>> timeit.repeat('sorted(set(l), key=l.index)', setup)
[23.231241687943111, 23.302754517266294, 23.29650511717773]
>>> timeit.repeat('seen = set(); [i for i in l if i not in seen and seen.add(i) is None]', setup)
[49.855933579601697, 50.171151882997947, 51.024657420945005]
```

Here we see that for a larger case where, the contain test that Jon uses for every element becomes relatively very costly, and since insertion order is quickly determined by index in this case, this method is much more efficient.

However, by appending more elements to the end of the list, we see that Jon's method does not bear much increased cost, whereas mine does:

```
>>> setup = 'l = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]*100 + [8,7,6,5]'
>>> timeit.repeat('sorted(set(l), key=l.index)', setup)
[93.221347206941573, 93.013769266020972, 92.64512197257136]
>>> timeit.repeat('seen = set(); [i for i in l if i not in seen and seen.add(i) is None]', setup)
[51.042504915545578, 51.059295348750311, 50.979311841569142]
```

I think I'd prefer Jon's method with a seen set, given the bad lookup times for the index.