# Remove duplicates from a list of lists based on duplicate first elements

Tags: python, list

data is below

```
data = [["'id'", "'state'", "'country'\n"],
        ['44', "'WD'", "'India'\n"],
        ['5', "'WD'", "'India'\n"],
        ['44', "'WD'", "'Japan'\n"],
        ['390', "'WD'", "'Japan'\n"],
        ['17', "'WD'", "'Japan'\n"],
        ['17', "'WD'", "'BEL'"]]
```

How to remove the duplicate elements in id.

Here 44, 17 id is repeating

Expected

```
[["'id'", "'state'", "'country'\n"]
['44', '1', "'WD'", "'India'\n"]
['5', "'WD'", "'India'\n"]
['390', "'WD'", "'Japan'\n"]
['17', "'WD'", "'Japan'\n"]]
```

Pseudo code

```
l = []

for i in range(len(a)):
    print (a[i])
    if i[0] == a[i][1]:
        pass
    else:
        l.append(i)
```

Comment: Did you run your "psuedo" code? What happened?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, it will not remove since i is not doing the counter job

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"i is not doing the counter job"*?!

Comment: The pseudocode is invalid as i is an integer and thus i[0] will throw an exception

Comment: @jonrsharpe first is i=0,1,2,3,4,5,6 the logic, take the first list take the first element and check the entire list where id is repeating if repeating remove.

Comment: And which how do you choose which version should remain? In your example you have the ID 44 with two different countries associated and expected the one which is associated with India to remain. Based on which criteria did you make that decision?

Comment: @DonFoumare like any duplicate second element will remove first one remain in the list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove duplicates in a list of lists based on the third item in each sublist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24295578/remove-duplicates-in-a-list-of-lists-based-on-the-third-item-in-each-sublist)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `dict` here:

```
unique_data = {}

for sub_data in data:
    sub_data_id = sub_data[0]

    if sub_data_id not in unique_data:
        unique_data[sub_data_id] = sub_data
```

The structure of `unique_data` will be like this:

```
{
    "'id'": ["'id'", "'state'", "'country'"], 
    '44': ['44', '1', "'WD'", "'India'"], 
    '5': ['5', "'WD'", "'India'"], 
    '390': ['390', "'WD'", "'Japan'"], 
    '17': ['17', "'WD'", "'Japan'"]
}
```

To then get the unique items, we can use `list(unique_data.values())`, which gives us:

```
[["'id'", "'state'", "'country'"], ['44', '1', "'WD'", "'India'"], ['5', "'WD'", "'India'"], ['390', "'WD'", "'Japan'"], ['17', "'WD'", "'Japan'"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is perhaps overkill, but you could use `itertools.groupby` to solve it. groupby the key `x[0]` ie first element in the list and then take first value from the grouped values.

```
from itertools import groupby
data = [["'id'", "'state'", "'country'\n"], ['44', '1', "'WD'", "'India'\n"], ['5', "'WD'", "'India'\n"], ['44', "'WD'", "'Japan'\n"], ['390', "'WD'", "'Japan'\n"], ['17', "'WD'", "'Japan'\n"], ['17', "'WD'", "'BEL'"]]
key_function = lambda x : x[0]
data.sort(key=key_function)
result = [ list(values) [0] for _,values in groupby(data,key=key_function) ]
print(result)
```

OUTPUT

```
[["'id'", "'state'", "'country'\n"], ['17', "'WD'", "'Japan'\n"], ['390', "'WD'", "'Japan'\n"], ['44', '1', "'WD'", "'India'\n"], ['5', "'WD'", "'India'\n"]]
```

Comment: Okay, if OP didn't care list order.

Answer (score 1):

```py
data = [["'id'", "'state'", "'country'\n"], ['44', '1', "'WD'", "'India'\n"], ['5', "'WD'", "'India'\n"], ['44', "'WD'", "'Japan'\n"], ['390', "'WD'", "'Japan'\n"], ['17', "'WD'", "'Japan'\n"], ['17', "'WD'", "'BEL'"]]

ls={}
for each  in data:
    if not each[0] in ls:
        ls[each[0]] = each[1:len(each)]
```

```
print(ls)
{"'id'": ["'state'", "'country'\n"],
   '44': ['1', "'WD'", "'India'\n"],
   '5': ["'WD'", "'India'\n"], 
   '390': ["'WD'", "'Japan'\n"], 
   '17': ["'WD'", "'Japan'\n"]}
```

```
ourlist = [[k]+v for k,v in ls.items()]

print(ourlist)

[["'id'", "'state'", "'country'\n"], 
['44', '1', "'WD'", "'India'\n"],
['5', "'WD'", "'India'\n"],
['390', "'WD'", "'Japan'\n"],
['17', "'WD'", "'Japan'\n"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to put the values in a dictionary with the id being the key. Then you can simply take the values.

Example:

```py
data_dict = {elt[0]: elt for elt in reversed(data)}
unique_data = list(data_dict.values())
print(unique_data)
```

If you want to keep the order, you can use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead.

Comment: This will not meet OP's requirement of the duplicated items after the first item being removed, this removes the duplicates before the last item. I think you can meet this requirement by iterating through `reversed(data)`.

Comment: @MarioIshac You are right

Answer (score 0):

When you work with these types of data, you are better off using Pandas. You gain in flexibility and speed, avoiding unnecessary loops.

```
data = [["'id'", "'state'", "'country'\n"],
        ['44', "'WD'", "'India'\n"],
        ['5', "'WD'", "'India'\n"],
        ['44', "'WD'", "'Japan'\n"],
        ['390', "'WD'", "'Japan'\n"],
        ['17', "'WD'", "'Japan'\n"],
        ['17', "'WD'", "'BEL'"]]
           
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:],columns = data[0])
print(df.drop_duplicates(subset="'id'"))
```

Output:

```
    'id' 'state' 'country'\n
0   44    'WD'   'India'\n
1    5    'WD'   'India'\n
3  390    'WD'   'Japan'\n
4   17    'WD'   'Japan'\n
```